# What are top-level const qualifiers?

Tags: c++, constants

What does `const` at "top level" qualifier mean in C++?

And what are other levels?

For example:

```
int const *i;
int *const i;
int const *const i;
```

Comment: I don't know what you mean by examples but I added some const qualifiers that i'm familiar with.

Comment: Also see [Where is the definition of `top-level cv-qualifiers` in the C++11 Standard?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24676824/1708801)

Answer (score 65, accepted):

A top-level const qualifier affects the object itself.  Others are only
relevant with pointers and references.  They do not make the object
const, and only prevent modification through a path using the pointer or
reference.  Thus:

```
char x;
char const* p = &x;
```

This is not a top-level const, and none of the objects are immutable.
The expression `*p` cannot be used to modify `x`, but other expressions
can be; `x` is not const.  For that matter

```
*const_cast<char*>( p ) = 't'
```

is legal and well defined.

But

```
char const x = 't';
char const* p = &x;
```

This time, there is a top-level const on `x`, so `x` is immutable.  No
expression is allowed to change it (even if `const_cast` is used).  The
compiler may put `x` in read-only memory, and it may assume that the
value of `x` never changes, regardless of what other code may do.

To give the pointer top-level `const`, you'd write:

```
char x = 't';
char *const p = &x;
```

In this case, `p` will point to `x` forever; any attempt to change this 
is undefined behavior (and the compiler may put `p` in read-only memory,
or assume that `*p` refers to `x`, regardless of any other code).

Comment: One other point: when writing functions the top-level qualifiers of arguments are discarded. This means that `void foo(char const)` and `void foo(char)` are the same function (and in fact they can be interchanged). The reasoning is that since the argument is taken by copy, the caller does not care whether the copy can be modified or not, so it's transparent for her.

Comment: @MatthieuM. Good point, although not exactly true as stated.  The top-level qualifiers are ignored in a declaration, and in the type of the function.  In the definition, however, they still behave as usual within the function.  (Top level qualifiers are also ignored by `typeid` and template parameters, when matching exceptions to catch, and probably in some other cases I've forgotten.  In practice, they also have no effect on non-class type return values.)

Comment: Regarding the last example with `const p`: `p=0;` is an attempt to change `p`, but it doesn't have undefined behavior, it's just ill-formed.

Answer (score 16):

The two levels of const are:
* Low-level Const
* Top-level Const

You should look at top and low level const through references and pointers, because this is where they are relevant.

```
int i = 0;
int *p = &i;
int *const cp = &i;
const int *pc = &i;
const int *const cpc = &i;
```

In the code above, there are 4 different pointer declarations. Let's go through each of these,

`int *p`: **Normal Pointer** can be used for making changes to the underlying object and can be reassigned.

`int *const cp` (top-level const): **Const Pointer** can be used for making changes to the underlying object but cannot be reassigned. (Cannot change it to point to another object.)

`const int *pc` (low-level const): **Pointer to Const** cannot be used for making changes to the underlying object but can itself be reassigned.

`const int *const cpc` (both top and low-level const): **Const Pointer to a Const** can neither be used for making changes to the underlying object nor can itself be reassigned.

Also, top-level const is always ignored when assigned to another object, whereas low-level const isn't ignored.

```
int i = 0;
const int *pc = &i;
int *const cp = &i;

int *p1 = cp; // allowed
int *p2 = pc; // error, pc has type const int*
```

Hope this helped :)
FYI: C++ Primer has a lot of information about the same!!!

Comment: Thanks a lot, that is the most clear explanation.By the way C++ Primer is the book which lead me here.

Comment: "You should look at top and low level const through references and pointers, because this is where they are relevant". Ok but nobody never show an example with references

Answer (score 14):

The way it was explained to me, given:

```
[const] TYPE * [const] VARIABLE
```

*VARIABLE* is used to point to *data* of type *TYPE* through `*VARIABLE`

Draw a line through the `*` or multiple `*`s

1. If there is a `const` to the **left** of the `*` it applies to the
   **data** and the **data** cannot be changed: `*VARIABLE` cannot be assigned, except at initialization
2. If there is a `const` to the **right** of the `*` it applies to the
   *VARIABLE* and what the *VARIABLE* points to cannot be changed: `VARIABLE` cannot be assigned, except at initialization

So:

```
          |              left  right
int       *       i1;
          |              no    no     can change *i1 and i1

int const *       i2;     
          |              yes   no     cannot change *i2 but can change i2

int       * const i3;
          |              no    yes    can change *i3 but i3 cannot be changed

int const * const i4;
          |              yes   yes    cannot change *i4 or i4
```

Comment: `const` binds to the left. unless there is nothing to the left, then it binds to the right

Answer (score 13):

`int *const i` puts `const` at the top-level, whereas `int const *i` does not.

The first says that the pointer `i` itself is immutable, whereas the second says that the memory the pointer points to is immutable.

Whenever `const` appears immediately before or after the type of the identifier, that is considered a top-level qualifier.

Comment: Excellent and clear answer. P.S. `int const *i` equals to `const int *i` (all are low-level const). I use `const int *i` (low-level) to distinguish its const level more often from `int *const i` (top-level).

Comment: I'm struggling to understand "Whenever const appears immediately before or after the type of the identifier, that is considered a top-level qualifier." Does this not apply to `int const *i` because the `const` appears in the middle of the type of the identifier, which is in this case is `int *`?

Comment: @24n8 I am also struggling to understand