# Where is the definition of `top-level cv-qualifiers` in the C++11 Standard?

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer

In [the draft C++11 standard: N3337](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf) I found several references to `top-level cv-qualifiers`, but no definition.

Comment: There's a definition of cv-qualifiers, top-level is the standard english word, no need for a definition.

Comment: @Deduplicator as I note in my answer below there is a defect report no this and it was not rejected as `NAD` so I don't think it is obvious

Answer (score 24, accepted):

From Dan Saks's [Top-Level cv-Qualifiers in Function Parameters](https://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCAQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.dansaks.com%2Farticles%2F2000-02%2520Top-Level%2520cv-Qualifiers%2520in%2520Function%2520Parameters.pdf&ei=5Ym-U5DXJKq8ygO-44H4CQ&usg=AFQjCNFl_i63VN4r3yMozEA-bWhOkhYqjw&sig2=uCbuSWhJwtJ2CdyyceHQSw&bvm=bv.70138588,d.bGQ&cad=rja):

> In C++, a cv-qualifier that applies to the first level of a type is called a **toplevel** cv-qualifier. For example, in:
>
> ```
> T *const p;
> ```
>
> the top-level cv-qualifier is `const`, and in:
>
> ```
> T const *volatile q;
> ```
>
> the top-level cv-qualifier is `volatile`. On the other hand:
>
> ```
> T const volatile *q;
> ```
>
> has no top-level cv-qualifiers. In this case, the cv-qualifiers `const` and `volatile` appear at the second level.
>
> The signature of a function includes all cv-qualifiers appearing in that function’s parameter types, except for those qualifiers appearing at the top-level of a parameter type.
>
> For example, in:
>
> ```
> int f(char const *p);
> ```
>
> the `const` qualifier is not at the top level in the parameter declaration, so it is part of the function’s signature.
>
> On the other hand, in:
>
> ```
> int f(char *const p);
> ```
>
> the `const` qualifier is at the top level, so it is not part of the function’s signature. This function has the same signature as:
>
> ```
> int f(char *p);
> ```

I couldn't find a definition in the standard either but what I posted above is explicitly stated in N3337 §8.3.5-5

> After producing the list of parameter types, any top-level
> cv-qualifiers modifying a parameter type are deleted when forming the
> function type.

---

Edit:
At the time of writing the above post a definition in the standard could not be found but now there's one [as pointed out by Shafik](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29631969/1938163):

n4296 excerpt:

> In this International Standard, the notation cv (or cv1 , cv2 , etc.),
> used in the description of types, represents an arbitrary set of
> cv-qualifiers, i.e., one of {const}, {volatile}, {const, volatile}, or
> the empty set. For a type cv T, the top-level cv-qualifiers of that
> type are those denoted by cv. [Example: The type corresponding to the
> type-id const int& has no top-level cv-qualifiers. The type
> corresponding to the typeid volatile int * const has the top-level
> cv-qualifier const. For a class type C, the type corresponding to the
> type-id void (C::* volatile)(int) const has the top-level cv-qualifier
> volatile. — end example ]

In C++20 draft, N4713, the definition is found in §6.7.3 (5) ("CV-qualifiers" or [basic.type.qualifier])

Comment: It seems like the Standard doesn't have a definition for `top-level cv-qualifiers`. I'm accepting your answer for the excellent article provided above. Thanks.

Comment: @juanchopanza well it is a creative way to infer the definition but I am not sure that `8.3.5p5` is well specified without a definition. Which as I note in my answer is now at least part of the latest draft, although it could change once it becomes C++17 t least this issue is tracked via a defect report.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour thanks for giving me the chance to go and take a peek in the new standard. It seems n4296 added that definition at the time of writing this

Answer (score 7):

This question is the subject of [defect report 609: What is a “top-level” cv-qualifier?](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4458.html#609)  which says:

> The phrase “top-level cv-qualifier” is used numerous times in the Standard, but it is not defined. The phrase could be misunderstood to indicate that the const in something like const T& is at the “top level,” because where it appears is the highest level at which it is permitted: T& const is ill-formed.

and the proposed resolution suggests adding the following wording and note:

> For a type cv T, the top-level cv-qualifiers of that type are those denoted by cv. [Example: The type corresponding to the type-id “const int&” has no top-level cv-qualifiers. The type corresponding to the type-id “volatile int * const” has the top-level cv-qualifier const. For a class type C, the type corresponding to the type-id “void (C::* volatile)(int) const” has the top-level cv-qualifier volatile. —end example]

**Update**

The defect has changed status to [DRWP](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#609) which means it is now part of the latest draft standard and we can find the new wording in [N4527](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4527.pdf).

Answer (score 4):

I only found one instance of the phrase in the standard, and
that was in a non-normative note.  Lacking any other definition,
one must assume that the expression is interpreted as it would
be normally in English; that the qualifier is at the highest
level of the type declaration.  Of course, we generally write
the declarations (in plain text, not in C++) from left to right,
not from up to down, but the usual rules apply: left comes
before right, and up comes before down.  So for something like
`char *const p`, we would write it (in English): "p is a const
pointer to char".  (In this case, English is the exact opposite
of the order we would use in C++.  This isn't always the case,
however.)  Since the `const` modifies pointer, which is the left
most (top) element, it is a top level qualifier.

Comment: The left-most element in your example is `char`, which can also be qualified seperately from the pointer... Or are you talking about the English version? Your explanation is confusing.

Comment: @rubenvb I'm talking about the English version.  Finding the top-most in the C++ version requires parsing.  Which results in the English version, where it is left-most.

Comment: @rubenvb No.  You have to parse the declaration into English, and then take the left-most.  (Consider something like `void (*const fp)( char const* )`, where the first `const` is the top-most.)

Comment: Hm, with function pointers you'll have to ignore the arguments, and look at the function pointer variable's declaration, but still from right to left. For the record: `void(*const* fp)(char const* const)` has no top-level qualifiers. The right-most pointer in the `fp` part is unqualified. Anyways, C pointer syntax makes everyone's eyes bleed.

Comment: @rubenvb It's not just function pointers.  It's anytime we use parentheses in the type.