# Why does using std::remove_reference and std::remove_const in different order produce different results?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, type-traits

In the following code I have used `std::remove_const` and `std::remove_reference` but in different order in two cases which are giving different results:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <type_traits>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<string> ar = {"mnciitbhu"};
    cout<<boolalpha;
    cout<<"First case : "<<endl;
    for(const auto& x : ar)
    {
        // Using std::remove_const and std::remove_reference
        // at the same time
        typedef typename std::remove_const<
            typename std::remove_reference<decltype(x)>::type>::type TT;
        cout<<std::is_same<std::string, TT>::value<<endl;
        cout<<std::is_same<const std::string, TT>::value<<endl;
        cout<<std::is_same<const std::string&, TT>::value<<endl;
    }
    cout<<endl;
    cout<<"Second case : "<<endl;
    for(const auto& x : ar)
    {
        // Same as above but the order of using std::remove_reference
        // and std::remove_const changed
        typedef typename std::remove_reference<
            typename std::remove_const<decltype(x)>::type>::type TT;
        cout<<std::is_same<std::string, TT>::value<<endl;
        cout<<std::is_same<const std::string, TT>::value<<endl;
        cout<<std::is_same<const std::string&, TT>::value<<endl;
    } 
    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
First case : 
true
false
false

Second case : 
false
true
false
```

Check on [Coliru Viewer](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/10dfc0dd79c2e228)

My question is why does using `std::remove_const` and `std::remove_reference` in different order produce different results? Since I am removing both reference and `const`-ness, shouldn't the result be the same?

Comment: [This reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/remove_cv) would be a good start, and it even has a very similar example, but with a pointer.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[`remove_const`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/remove_cv) will only remove a [top-level](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24676976/241631) `const` qualifier, if one exists. In `const std::string&`, the `const` is not top-level, hence applying `remove_const` has no effect on it.

When you reverse the order and apply `remove_reference` first, the resulting type is `const string`; now the `const` is top-level and the subsequent application of `remove_const` will remove the `const` qualifier.