# Top-level or low-level constness or neither?

Tags: c++, c++11, constants

I'm working through the [C++ Primer](http://www.informit.com/store/c-plus-plus-primer-9780321714114) and if I understand it correctly:

- Top-level constness applies to the object itself.
- Low-level constness means that the the referenced object is const which makes the referenced object top-level const.

```
// A plain int.
int i {0};

// Top-level const ints.
const int ci {42};
const int ci2 {0};

// A low-level pointer to const int.
const int * pci {&ci};

// Low-level, because the referenced object can't be changed.
*pci = 0; // error

// But not top-level, because it can be changed to point to another object.
pci = &ci2; // fine

// This is both top-level and low-level const
// because both the pointer and the object it
// points to are const:
const int * const cpci {&ci};
*cpci = 0;   // error
cpci = &ci2; // error
```

Now the question. **Is there a naming convention for a constness which is neither top-level nor low-level?** I.e. the pointer itself is not const but it points in a constant way to a non-const object? Or is this a special case of low-level constness? Example:

```
int i {0];
int j {42};

// The following pointer is not const itself.
// The object it's pointing to is not const but
// it can't be manipulated through the pointer.
const int * pci {&i};
*pci = 42; // error

// All these are fine:
++i;
pci = &j;
++j;

*pci = 42; // error as above
```

**Edit after accepting Lightness Races in Orbit's answer:**
My IDE calls them **read-only pointers** which makes sense to me
although the referenced object can be changed with this ugly cast:

```
*const_cast<int*>(pci) = 21;
```

Comment: Migrate to Programmers.SE?

Comment: Note until recently [the standard did not even define top-level cv-qualifier](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29631969/1708801) so it will be hard to come up with one *correct* answer to this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, not really.

The distinction you're making is between an *object* with `const`-qualified type, and an *expression* with `const`-qualified type.

Since (from a usage perspective) it very rarely matters which one is in play<sup>†</sup>, there is no meaningful terminology to distinguish them in any given case.

This does admittedly make it a little cumbersome to explain why the following program is totally valid and well-defined (if really, really bad style), despite casting away the `const`:

```
void foo(const int& x)
{
   // the expression `x` has type `const int&` (before decay),
   // but after casting away the constness we can modify the
   // referent, because it happens to actually be non-`const`.
   const_cast<int&>(x) = 66;
}

int main()
{
   int x = 42;    // object is not const!
   foo(x);
}
```

For what it's worth, although ["top-level const" is standard terminology](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24676824/560648), I'm not so sure about your "low-level const". The terms aren't even properly symmetrical! Pfft.

<sub><sup>†</sup> In `foo()` above we wouldn't actually write the `const_cast` because we would assume that all inputs are references to objects that really are `const`.</sub>

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The top-level / low-level const terminology is used throughout the book so I thought they were commonly used.

Comment: @robsn: Turns out "top-level" is standard terminology.