# auto keyword and top-level, low-level constants

Tags: c++, constants, auto

In C++ Primer, it is mentioned that, `auto` ordinarily ignores top-level constants. As usual, in initializations, low-level constants, such as when initializing a pointer to a constant are kept.

```
const int ci = i, &cr = ci; 
auto b = ci; // ok:b is an int (top level constants in ci is ignored)
auto d = &i; // d is an int* (& of a int object is int *)
auto e = &ci; // e is a const int *(& of a constant object is a low level constant)
```

Now, my question is: In the 2nd statement, `const` is ignored and type of `b` is `int`.
But in the last statement, the `const` of `ci` is not ignored and the type is `const int*`, rather than `int*`. Why?

Comment: Show declaration of `i`

Comment: you answered your own question, after `&ci` the `const` is one level of indirection away, but only top-level consts are ignored

Comment: int i;
What i know is, if the object is itself constant, the constant is top-level , otherwise low level. I don't know exactly what these terms mean. I didn't get your statement, "one level of indirection away"?

Comment: "level" means "level of indirection" in all this

Comment: What does that mean exactly.

Comment: See [What are top-level qualifiers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7914444/what-are-top-level-const-qualifiers)

Comment: Also, [Where is the definition of `top-level cv-qualifiers` in the C++11 Standard?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24676824/where-is-the-definition-of-top-level-cv-qualifiers-in-the-c11-standard)

Answer (score 3):

When you use `auto b=ci;`, you create a copy of `ci`.So C++ has no reason to prevent you from changing the value of `b`.
But if you use `auto e=&ci;`, you will create a pointer of const int variable `ci`. `e` should be a pointer on a constant value to prevent you from changing the value of `ci`.

Comment: `e` is not `const`

Comment: type of e is const int *. It is constant

Comment: @NamanSharma `const int *` is not const. it *points to* a const int.

Comment: This thing i know. Tell me just one thing: & of a constant object is low level constant. how??

Comment: What you want to know is the reason why the type of `e` is const int *, rather than int *, right?

Answer (score 1):

The use of

```
const int i = ...;
```

to define a `const` object has been a source of confusion for a long time. It makes people think that;

```
const int* ptr = ...;
```

also defines a `const` pointer. That would be an erroneous conclusion. If you move the `const` a bit, it is less confusing.

```
int i = ...;                 // Defines i to be a non-const object
int const i = ...;           // Defines i to be a const object

int* ptr = ...;              // Defines ptr to be a non-const pointer to a non-const object
int const* ptr = ...;        // Defines ptr to be a non-const pointer to a const object
int* const ptr = ...;        // Defines ptr to be a const pointer to a non-const object
int const* const ptr = ...;  // Defines ptr to be a const pointer to a const object
```

Coming to the issue of top level cv-qualifiers,

```
int const i = ...;
```

defines an object whose type is `int` and it has `const` qualifier.

```
int volatile i = ...;
```

defines an object whose type is `int` and it has `volatile` qualifier.

```
int const* ptr = ...;
```

defines an object whose type is `int const*` but it has no `const` or `volatile` qualifier. The second-level type, `int` has `const` qualifier but not the top level type.

```
int const* const ptr = ...;
```

defines an object whose type is `int const*` and it has `const` qualifier. The second-level type, `int`, also has `const` qualifier.

```
int * const ptr = ...;
```

defines an object whose type is `int*` and it has `const` qualifier. The second-level type, `int`, has no `const` qualifier.

**More info:**

[Where is the definition of `top-level cv-qualifiers` in the C++11 Standard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24676824/where-is-the-definition-of-top-level-cv-qualifiers-in-the-c11-standard)
[What are top-level const qualifiers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7914444/what-are-top-level-const-qualifiers)

Answer (score 0):

It is a low level constant because it is directly referencing it. `auto b = ci` copies the value of `ci` to `b`, but `auto e = &ci` has to have some `const`-ness, as it does NOT copy `ci`, but instead points to where `ci` exists. The term low level means, in this case, that there is not much indirection.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to mention `int i=0;`
Here `i` can change in the context of the program which makes it non-constant.

> In the 2nd statement, const is ignored

So,there is no top-level const to be ignored

Actual code in C++ Primer,

```
int i = 0;//Value of i is 0 but it might change
const int ci = i;//Value of ci will not change once initialized
auto d = &i;//Hence d is an int*(No top-level const)
```

> in the last statement, the const of ci is not ignored

& of a const object is a low-level const which `auto` doesn't ignore

```
auto e = &ci;// e is const int*(low-level const)
```