# How do I print a constant value at compile time?

Tags: c++, templates, template-meta-programming

With template metaprogramming, the [TD trick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29917309/3198247) can be used to print the *type* of expressions as an error message at compile time.

This is really useful to debug templates. Is there a similar way to print *values* that are computed at compile-time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, and the code looks really similar: You declare (but not define) a `template struct` that has the value as a template parameter. By trying to instantiate it without defining it, you get a compiler error that spells out the constant value:

```
template <int val>
struct PrintConst;

PrintConst<12*34> p;
```

When compiling this code, `g++` fails with the following error:

```
const-display.cpp:4:19: error: aggregate ‘PrintConst<408> p’ has incomplete type and cannot be defined
 PrintConst<12*34> p;
                   ^
```

Note that it shows both the expression `12*34`, as well as the resulting value `408`.

Comment: How do you do this without breaking compilation?

Comment: @SergeyA AFAIK, there is no way, unless you are somehow able to cause a warning instead of an error. (Which might still break compilation when using -Werror or equivalent compile flags.)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `static_assert` for this job too:

```
template<int val>
void static_print()
{
    static_assert(val & false, "");
}

int main()
{
    static_print<12*34>();
}
```

which output on g++:

```
x.cc: In instantiation of ‘void static_print() [with int val = 408]’:
x.cc:9:22:   required from here
x.cc:4:20: error: static assertion failed
  static_assert(val & false, "");
```

or in clang:

```
x.cc:9:2: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'static_print<408>' requested here
    static_print<12*34>();
    ^
```

Comment: I originally thought about using static_assert, too, but it only printed the expression (like in the last line of your error message). I like the idea of using it inside a function as as a kind of indirection! I'm not quite sure which answer to accept - yours looks nicer to use, but mine is shorter to write (which might be handy if it is used as a quick&dirty debugging aid and removed from the code again afterwards)...

Comment: @anderas Just as a correction, both messages show the results, but gcc does not show the original expression. Anyway, I think you should accept the one that it is most compelling to you, or just does not accept anyone. What I like this answer is the fact that you can put any message that you want aside the test.