# How do we print out the value_type of a C++ STL container?

Tags: c++, stl

I know that STL containers have a `value_type` parameter and I've seen how it can be used to declare a type of a variable like:

```
vector<int>::value_type foo;
```

But can we just print this `value_type` to a console?

I want to see "string" in this example:

```
int main() {
    vector<string> v = {"apple", "facebook", "microsoft", "google"};
    cout << v << endl;
    cout << v.value_type << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The symbol `value_type` is not a member variable, it's a scoped type-name. Would you expect to be able to print the value of the keyword `int`?

Comment: it's just a type, so you want to get type name as string?

Comment: Quite possible, but you'll need to add some code.

Comment: That would be equivalent to `cout << string;`, which is not the same as `cout << "string";`.

Comment: yeah @molbdnilo I want a type as human readable string

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Template which prints the name of the given type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25891266/template-which-prints-the-name-of-the-given-type)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`X::value_type` is no different from any other type alias (aka typedef) in this regard — C++ has no native way of converting a type to its source code string representation (not the least because that could be ambiguous). What you can do is use `std::type_info::name`:

```
cout << typeid(decltype(v)::value_type).name() << endl;
```

The resulting text is compiler dependent (and not even guaranteed to be easily human readable). It will be consistent within the same build of a program, but you cannot expect it to be the same across different compilers. In other words, it's useful for debugging, but cannot reliably be used in a persistent fashion.

Comment: Thank you, on my machine it gives me `NSt3__112basic_stringIcNS_11char_traitsIcEENS_9allocatorIcEEEE`

Comment: @You can use `__cxa_demangle` to get a readable type name: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23266701/1968

Comment: Isn't it only for gcc?

Comment: @Niakrais: Not quite, it's for all compilers/platforms combinations using the Itanium ABI. The Itanium ABI is used on all Linux/MacOS platforms by all mainstream C++ compilers; the only widespread platform not using it is Windows, and thus MSVC and Clang in MSVC-compatible mode will not use it. Even on Windows, using Cygwin or MinGW means using the Itanium ABI.

Answer (score 5):

In addition to the `typeid`-based answer, I see one further possibility using Boost like this:

```
#include <boost/type_index.hpp>

cout << boost::typeindex::type_id_with_cvr<decltype(v)::value_type>().pretty_name() << "\n";
```

The advantage is a portable, human-readable name that includes const/volatile qualifications and is consistent across major compilers and systems. The output on my machine is

```
// when compiled with gcc:
std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >
// ... and with clang:
std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >
```

Decide for yourself whether this output qualifies as "human-readable", but also compare it to the `typeid(...).name()` approach, which on my machine gives:

```
NSt3__112basic_stringIcNS_11char_traitsIcEENS_9allocatorIcEEEE
```

Answer (score 1):

It's probably **safe to assume that you need this type info for debug purposes**(?).
If it is, don't forget gdb's built in `whatis` and `ptype` commands:

```
$ cat main.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    vector<string> v = {"apple", "facebook", "microsoft", "google" };
    cout << v[2] << endl;
    // cout << v.value_type << endl;
    return 0;
}
$ cat gdbCommands.txt
break main
run
next
next
whatis v
quit
$ g++ -ggdb -o main main.cpp
$ gdb -x gdbCommands.txt ./main
GNU gdb (Ubuntu 8.0.1-0ubuntu1) 8.0.1
// bla bla bla ...
type = std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a rather [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25891266/499359) some time ago. The answer there shown a function able to translate a type into a human readable string:

```
template <typename T> std::string TypeName() {
    auto name = typeid(T()).name();  // function type, not a constructor call!
    int status = 0;

    std::unique_ptr<char, void(*)(void*)> res {
        abi::__cxa_demangle(name, NULL, NULL, &status),
        std::free
    };

    std::string ret((status == 0) ? res.get() : name);
    if (ret.substr(ret.size() - 3) == " ()") ret.resize(ret.size() - 3);
    return ret;
}
```

Once you have this `TypeName` function you can achieve your goal:

```
int main() {
    vector<string> v = {"apple", "facebook", "microsoft", "google" };
    cout << v << endl;
    cout << TypeName<v.value_type>() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Which should output (GCC HEAD 9 201809):

> ```
> std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >
> ```

Answer (score 1):

If it's for debug purpose, then this solution would work without any dependencies:

```
#include <regex>

template <typename T>
struct TypeToNameT
{
    static std::string getTypeFromName() {
#ifdef _MSC_VER
        std::regex re("<(.*)>::.*");
        std::string templateType(__FUNCTION__);
#else
        std::regex re(" = (.*);");
        std::string templateType(__PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
#endif
        std::smatch match;
        try
        {
            if (std::regex_search(templateType, match, re) && match.size() > 1)
                return match.str(1);
        }
        catch (std::regex_error& e) {
            // Syntax error in the regular expression
        }
        return "";
    }
};
/** Get the templated type name. This does not depends on RTTI, but on the preprocessor, so it should be quite safe to use even on old compilers */
template <typename T>
std::string getTypeName() { return TypeToNameT<T>::getTypeFromName(); }


int main() {
    std::vector<std::string> v = {"apple", "facebook", "microsoft", "google" };
    std::cout << getTypeName<decltype(v)::value_type>() << std::endl;  // Returns: "std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>"
    return 0;
}
```

Unlike the `typeid` based answer, this use the preprocessor and as such is not subject to name mangling (so the name is... **readable**).

Please notice that you can't use `v.value_type` as a type directly, it's not part of the instance `v` but of the type of `v`: `std::vector<std::string>`

The regex part is because the `std::string` class is too dumb and you need such oddities for a simple search/split code. If you have a decent string class, you'll not need regex here for extracting the part that's after the "=" string and before the ";".

Comment: `__FUNCTION__` prints just the function name, without any additional information. You want `__FUNCSIG__`.

Comment: Just tried it here: http://rextester.com/FDZT51977 and it seems to work with __FUNCTION__. With __FUNCSIG__, the regex must be modified since the signature is more complex. In all cases, thanks, I did not know about __FUNCSIG__ before.

Comment: Nevermind, you're right. `__FUNCTION__` doesn't contain template parameters of the function itself, so when I used this trick before, I resorted to use `__FUNCSIG__`. But it missed me that it contains the template parameters of enclosing classes. That's a nice idea.