# gcc compiler not show warning when method override and omit const

Tags: c++, gcc, clang, overriding, constants

Why this is compiled without warning?

```
struct A{
    virtual void get(int const x) = 0;
};

struct B : public A{
    virtual void get(int x) override{

    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    B b;
    b.get(6);

    return 0;
}
```

Here is the output:

```
g++ -std=c++11 -Wall ./x.cc
clang -std=c++11 -Wall ./x.cc -lstdc++
```

If I add `-Wextra` I get messages for unused function parameters, but still nothing about the const.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The method signatures are exactly the same, so there is no problem with the code. If they didn't match, you would expect an error, not a warning.

Why are the signatures the same? Because top level `const`s get ignored<sup>1</sup>. These three are duplicate declarations:

```
void foo(const int); // declaration of foo(int)
void foo(int const); // re-declaration of foo(int)
void foo(int);       // re-declaration of foo(int)
```

It is best to omit top level `const` from function declarations because they are at best confusing. You *can* use `const` in the function definition as an implementation detail, in the same way as you can declare any local variable `const` if you don't want it to be modified.

```
void foo(const int n)
{
  // n is const here. I know that is shouldn't be changed so I enforce it.
}
```

---

<sup>1</sup> **See also**: [*What are top-level `const` qualifiers?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7914444/what-are-top-level-const-qualifiers)

Comment: Might be worth explaining what "top level" means here. I get it, you get it, but the OP may not understand the distinction when comparing `int const*` to `int const&` to `int const` and how this relates to the actual reasoning for the rule (which is pointlessness of `const` on an object passed by value, at least in the original declaration).

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Good point. I added a link to a related SO post.