# cannot convert 'const char **' to 'const char*'

Tags: c++, arrays, char

Good morning everyone!  I am trying to create a fork/exec call from a parent program via a passed '-e' parameter (e.g. parent -e child key1=val1 ...).  As a result I want to copy all the values after the first two in the argv array into a new array child_argv.  Something like:

```
const char *child_argv[10];  // this is actually a global variable
static const char *sExecute;

      int I = 0;
const char *Value = argv[1];
    sExecute = Value;

      for (i=2; i<argc; i++) {
             child_argv[I] = argv[i];
             I++;
      }
    child_argv[I] = NULL;   // terminate the last array index with NULL
```

This way I can call the exec side via something like:

```
execl(sExecute, child_argv);
```

However I get the error message "error: cannot convert 'const char**' to 'const char*' for argument '2' to 'execl(const char*, const char*, ...)'".  I have even tried to use an intermediate step:

```
const char *child_argv[10];  // this is actually a global variable
static const char *sExecute;

      int I = 0;
const char *Value = argv[1];
    sExecute = Value;

      for (i=2; i<argc; i++) {
    const char *Value = argv[i+1];
             child_argv[I] = Value;
             I++;
      }
    child_argv[I] = NULL;   // terminate the last array index with NULL
```

But I can't figure this out.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

UPDATE

As was pointed out, I should be using 'execv' instead of 'execl' in this situation. Still getting errors though...

UPDATE 2

I ended up copying the array without the desired parameters of argv.  See the post here to see the result [How to copy portions of an array into another array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32233513/how-to-copy-portions-of-an-array-into-another-array/32233594?noredirect=1#comment52352712_32233594)

Comment: Your code doesn't include the `execl` call which is the source of the compile error. But like the error suggests, you are passing in `child_argv` (of type `const char**`) when it wants a `const char*`.

Comment: I recommend you read [the `execl` manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/exec.3.html), and the reason for the error should be pretty obvious. Actually, if you *read the error message*, you would understand the reason as well.

Comment: @Barry the 'execl' call was included in the post.  How can I be passing a const char** when child_argv was created as an array of const char*?

Answer (score 2):

From here: http://linux.die.net/man/3/exec

I think you mean to call "execv" not "execl". Execl seems to take a variable number of arguments, expecting each const char * to be another argument, while execv takes an array of arguments.

Comment: Oppps, looking back over the reference material, you are right!  I updated to use 'execv', but now I'm getting the error "error: invalid conversion from 'const char**' to 'char* const*' [-fpermissive]"

Comment: you might want to read this I guess, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7914444/what-are-top-level-const-qualifiers, but it sounds like you need to change `const char *child_argv[10];` to `const char * const child_argv[10];` or something along these lines.

Comment: @user the point is that execl expects to be passed an array of constant strings. when you make your type be `const char *child_argv[10]`, that is a constant array of non constant strings. so you need to make it an array of constant strings (in any number of ways) to make the warnings go away.

Comment: @Beck I have tried several things but can't figure this out.  C++ is not my programming language of choice...  Any other thoughts?

Comment: Really you just need to follow link above and read the answer to that question very carefully. Or, post a new question about this. (But most likely it will be marked as a duplicated.) If you really just want to tap out on this and move on, you could use a `const_cast` to just get the consts right. That will look pretty ugly to C++ programmers though.

Comment: @Beck I've been struggling with this for two days.  At this point I could care less if it's ugly or not, I just want to get beyond this hurtle.  I looked into both links and I'm still in the same position.  I will tap out on this and just ask a different question.  Thanks for your help though!

Answer (score 0):

You should be using execv. When you convert to execv, for some reason execv expects a array of non-const pointers instead of const pointers, so you either have to just cast the array to (char**) or copy the strings into (char*) pointers.

Comment: Thanks for the help pinkhorror!  I thought I was copying the strings into (char*) pointers in the second example listed above using the 'Value' variable... apparently not...  Any thoughts?

Comment: Your child_argv is an array of `const char*`. `execv` has an array of (char*) as its expected argument (I don't know why, but it does.)
With C types, I'm probably simplifying a bit, but you read right to left. 
So, `const char* child_argv[10]` is a 10-element array of pointers to chars that are const.
execv has this as it's second argument:
`char *const argv[]`
So, that's an array of const pointers to chars. It promises not to modify the pointers themselves, but the chars they point to are fair game.

Comment: thanks for the help!  So are you saying I need to change "const char* child_argv[10]" to "char *const argv[]"?  Sorry about this... As stated I've worked on this for two days, I'm tired, I'm frustrated, and this problem is holding up development on several fronts.

Comment: Thanks again for your help, I ended up going at this from a different direction and have updated the post to reflect that.