# How to copy portions of an array into another array

Tags: c++, arrays

Good morning!  I need to copy a portion of one array into another array starting at position 2 and consuming all the remaining value.  The first array is the 'argv' array of type 'char**' but the second array needs to be of type 'const char*'.  It appears that there are two ways to do this in C++ - std:copy and memcpy.  Which would be better to handle this situation since the two arrays are of different types and what would an example look like?

Comment: Aren't you supposed to *append* the entries in the `argv` array into the destination string? That sounds more logical to me.

Comment: Some code with what you have tried would be nice.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Good of you to remind me, good night everyone! :)

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: tata ;p

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There's very few good reasons to use `memcpy()` in C++. If I understand what you're asking correctly, here's an example of how to do it using `std::copy()`.

```
vector<char*> args(argc - 2);
copy(argv + 2, argv + argc, begin(args));
```

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/aacf03f189d3e1f7).

Comment: A two-line code dump without explanation, particularly one with a container of pointers, is harmful, not useful.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Lazy questions get lazy answers.

Comment: @matttnewport thanks for the answer!  When I pass the 'args' array in my 'execv' call, I get an error "error: cannot convert 'std::vector<const char*>' to 'char* const*' for argument '2' to 'int execv(const char*, const* char*, ...)"

Comment: @user1646428: Where does your question say that you're using `execv`?

Comment: @lightness The post does not mention it, but I did state what the two arrays should consist of.

Comment: @user1646428 you need to pass `args.data()` not `args` to `execv()` since it expects a C style array not an `std::vector`. According to the man page for `execv()` you should also add a null terminator to the array, so you'll want a call to `args.push_back(nullptr)` before calling `execv()`.

Comment: @mattnewport Thanks again for your help.  I have added both of those modifications in the codebase but now get the error "error: invalid conversion from 'const char**' to 'char* const*' [-fpermissive]".  That error is pointing to the brackets of the args.data() reference.

Comment: @user1646428 It appears `execv()` expects a non-const char* array argument. You should declare your vector as `vector<char*>` rather than `vector<const char*>`

Comment: @mattnewport as stated above, with your corrections the program now compiles, but for some reason the execv is not running.  More testing I suppose...  Thanks again!

Comment: @user1646428: Well then you stated it wrong because you didn't mention `const* char*` at all.

Comment: @Lightness The error has actually changed depending on what code was used.  You must be having a bad day... all your posts seem rather negative.

Answer (score 0):

Or am I misunderstanding your question? That you have a string containing space-delimited "arguments" and are supposed to create an argv-style array?

Then I would suggest using [`std::copy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy) together with [`std::istringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream), [`std::istream_iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istream_iterator) and [`std::back_inserter`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_inserter), something like this:

```
std::vector<std::string> args;
std::istringstream istr(string_containing_args);

std::copy(std::istream_iterator<std::string>(istr),
          std::istream_iterator<std::string>(),
          std::back_inserter(args));
```

Now you have a vector of strings, similar to an `argv` array. The problem here is that you seem to be wanting a proper `argv` style array, to pass to e.g. `execv`. This can be done by [transforming](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform) the vector into another vector:

```
std::vector<const char*> execv_args(args.size());
std::transform(std::begin(args), std::end(args),
               std::begin(execv_args),
               [](const std::string& s){ return s.c_str(); });
execv_args.push_back(nullptr);
```

<sub>Important note: The `args` vector must have a lifetime that exceeds the lifetime of the `execv_args` array, or the pointers will become invalid.</sub>

Now the final vector could be used like e.g.

```
execv(execv_args[0], &execv_args[1]);
```

Comment: I believe he is starting with an array of strings (from `argv`) and wants to pass some of them to `execv()` rather than starting with a space delimited argument string.

Comment: @mattnewport that's exactly what I'm trying to do!  The software will now compile with your last reply to your answer so I'm testing a few things real quick...