# Pointers,constants and Type aliasis

Tags: c++, pointers, constants

What is the difference between the following:

```
const char *c = 0; //Here c is a pointer to a constant character

typedef char *pstring;
const pstring cstr = 0 //cstr is a constant pointer to a character
```

Why is there a difference between the two statements, while they look just the same.In C++ Primer it is mentioned that the base type of first statement is const char and * is the part of the declarator. While for the last statement,the base type is const pstring. I am not getting the difference between the two.

Comment: A pstring is a pointer to a char, so a const pstring is a const pointer to a char.

Answer (score 8):

I think your confusion stems from not knowing about top-level `const`. When you have a `typedef`, you cannot add `const` to the underlying type, only above it.

`const pstring p` is not the same as `const char *p` i.e. `typedef`s are not macro substitutions. Once `typedef`ed the type is atomic; it doesn't matter where the `const` is, be it to the left or right of the type the `const`ness is associated with the complete type, in this case `char*`.

```
typedef char* pstring;
const pstring p1;  // const pointer to char i.e. char* const
pstring const p2;  // const pointer to char i.e. char* const
```

If you have the original type written as it is then the meaning will change.

```
const char* p1;  // pointer to const char
char* const p2;  // const pointer to char
```

[What are top-level const qualifiers?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7914444/183120) Read to know more.

Answer (score 3):

Read pointer declarations from right to left helps to make sense of them.

First one is a pointer to a char that is a const. You can't modify the char that it points to, because the *char* is const.

Second one is a const pointer to a char. You can't modify the value of the pointer (the location of the char it points to), because the *pointer* is const.

Following a `typedef char* pstring` (and it's a good idea to move the asterisk away from your typename, as it isn't part of it), the constness applies to the type that it creates, as it does with everything else:

```
int i;
const int i = 0; // actually int const i = 0

char* p;
const char* p = 0; // actually char const* p = 0

typedef char* pstring;
const pstring ps = 0; // actually 'pstring const' -> 'char* const' ps = 0
```

Exactly for this reason, some coding standards (e.g. MISRA) require you to place the cv qualifiers after the type name, because it works better to show that the const-ness qualifies the type, it's dependent on it - and not the other way around.

Comment: @NamanSharma you're welcome.:) if you've found it helpful, please consider upvoting / accepting. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
const char *c = 0;
```

This declares `c` to be a pointer to `const char`. You cannot change what `c` points to through `c`. However `c` can point to a different string.

```
char arr[] = "test";
c = arr; // OK
```

On other other hand.

```
typedef char *pstring;
const pstring cstr = 0;
```

declares  `cstr` to be `const` pointer to `char`. You can change what `cstr` points to but you cannot change where `cstr` points to. Without the `typedef`, you would use:

```
char* const cstr = 0;
```

Unfortunately, the language allows `const` to be place before the fundamental type. It will be much clearer to use:

```
char const* c = 0;     // what c points to is const
```

Read from right to left. `c` is a pointer to `const` `char`.

```
char* const cstr = 0;  // the pointer is const
```

Read from right to left. `c` is a `const` pointer to `char`.

IMO, the `const`-ness of the pointer and the object it points is clearer with the above.

Comment: I know the difference between constant pointer and pointer to a constant character. The problem is when we use 
: typedef int num , then every occurence of int is replaced with num.
So now if we write typedef char * pstring , then the statement const pstring would be const char* (I have just replaced pstring with char *, what's wrong here)

Comment: @NamanSharma, *then every occurence of int is replaced with num.* sort of true. It's not like macro substitution.

Comment: So what you mean to say is we do not actually substitute, it is just a way of writing. But it is confusing in case of pointers.

Comment: @NamanSharma, a `typedef` is treated as an alias for the type. In your case, if you can combine `char*` into a type, `const pstring` would be like `const "char*"`, not `"const char"*`.