# Why auto type specifier ignores the top-level const?

Tags: c++, c++11, auto, decltype, rvalue

The quotations below are all from the book: **C++ Primer 5th ed.**"

quote 1

> `auto` ordinarily ignores top-level consts. As usually in
>   initialization. [low-level const](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7914444/what-are-top-level-const-qualifiers), such as when an initalizer is a
>   pointer to const, are kept. *( -- pp.69)*

quote 2

> When the expression to which we apply `decltype` is a variable,
>   `decltype` returns the type of that variable, including top-level
>   const and references (*-- pp. 70*).

Compare with `decltype`, **why auto drops the top-level const in type deducing?**, then I found:

> `auto` tells the compiler to deduce the type from the initializer, But
>   implication, a variable that uses `auto` as its type specifier must have
>   an initializer (*-- pp. 69*)

**My Understanding** so far is: `auto` infers the type from the initializer. The initilizer is rvalue type which is not saved in the stack, therefore, it has no top-level const at all. Because of this, auto drops the top-level const during type deducing.

I don't know if my understanding is correct or wrong, please correct it if it is wrong.

Comment: You can read what [the documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction) has to say about that and see if it is consistent with your understanding. But whatever your understanding is: It's probably a simplification of the actual rules that work out ok most of the time.

Comment: `auto x = y;` is making a copy of `y`, so it is not really relevant that `y` is const. You might want to make a non-const copy of a const object.

Comment: ... And making an explicitly `const` copy can be expressed easily in the language. Doing the opposite, declaring it *should not* be `const`, not so much.

Comment: If it didn't ignore the top-level const and you wanted it to be non-const how would you do this? There is no `not_const` keyword in C++.

Comment: @RichardCritten well, there is `mutable`...